# How do I receive mail from Gmail within my ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

How do I receive mail from Gmail within my ASP.NET application? Is there a Gmail API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google allows one to enable IMAP support on their GMail account.  Then you can use an IMAP library to access the inbox (i.e. read (mark) messages, delete messages etc.)

Of course, you don't *have* to use a library. You could implement your own IMAP client but a library will make it a lot easier for you.

Here are a couple of possible IMAP libraries for .NET:

- [interimap.codeplex.com/](http://interimap.codeplex.com/)
- [www.rebex.net/mail.net/tutorial-imap.aspx](http://www.rebex.net/mail.net/tutorial-imap.aspx)

As @Douglas suggested, of course, IMAP need not be your only option. If you have a preference for POP3 you could just as well use a POP3 library.

Comment: I've already activated that function for my account. Please, describe more detailed the IMAP library and where I can get it. Thanks!

Comment: Or, if you’ll only be downloading your Gmail messages from this application, you could consider POP3.

Comment: Does POP3 allow me to read new messages only? As far as I've investigated, it allows to read messages using RETR [message number]

Comment: Yes, generally speaking, with POP you're limited to download & optionally delete messages marked as unread/new only. IMAP is a more complete/powerful protocol.

Comment: Seems, that I need to use IMAP, because all messages should be downloaded, even already read ones from e.g. Gmail